# Access Window height/width via jQuery Webworker?

Tags: jquery

Can anyone advise if it's possible to access the browser's height/width from inside a jQuery webworker process?

This doesn't return anything:

```html
function getWindowDimensions() {
    output = "Screen width: " + $(window).width();
    output += "<br />";
    output += "Screen height: " + $(window).height();

    postMessage(output);
    setTimeout("timedCount()", 100);
}

getWindowDimensions();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSfiddle :- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rBdx/711/)

```
alert("Width: " + $(window).width());
alert("Height: " + $(window).height());
```

Comment: The problem is that that doesn't work within a web-worker process.